# Hibernate OneToMany generated foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following table structure:

```
parent(parentId)
child(childId, parentId fk)
```

Then, I have the following objects:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(...)
   private String id;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
   Set<Child> children
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(...)
   private String id;

   @Column(...)
   private String parentId;

}
```

Now, I create a transient parent and child, and I add the child to the parent, then save the parent:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.children.add(new Child());

parentDao.save(parent);
```

I get the exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value
```

**My question:** How can I get the parentId in the child class to automatically be set to the value generated by the insertion of the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would re-arange your class structure as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(...)
   private String id;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
   Set<Child> children
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(...)
   private String id;

   @Column(...)
   private Parent parent;

}
```

Then when hibernate fetches the parent class, and initializes the set of children, the child class will have a reference to the parent class.  Then to get the parentId, you would call:

```
Child c = new Child()....
c.parent.id;
```

Comment: Hi sqrfv, thank you for the response.  Please see my comment under Ryan's answer.  Thanks

Comment: In DB work, it is very uncommon for an Id to reference more than one table.  If the parent could be anything than you could use java class hierarchy and have all the parent type classes extend or implement some structure that the child could reference.  If its a question of joining the tables, check out this example of a many-to-many relationship.  The join is used in the second class (courses).  http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-using-annotations-1.html

Answer (score 2):

Your child shouldn't have a `private String parentId`, but a `private Parent parent`, and when you `parent.children.add(child)`, you must also `child.setParent(parent)`. See the [prototypical parent-child relationship example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/example-parentchild.html) in the Hibernate reference and the [bidi one-to-many section](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1591) of the annotation reference.

Comment: I guess, so you are saying the child needs to know the parent type?  If this is not possible (meaning that the parent could be one of many entity types), then should I be using a Join table for each parent type?

Comment: "Parent could be one of many entity types" doesn't sound like a parent-child relationship. It sounds like it might be a [unidirectional one-to-many](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join-12m). If all parent objects are part of the same inheritance hierarchy, it could also be an [inheritance mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html). Finally, there's a little-known "many-to-any" mapping that's mentioned in the inheritance chapter, too.